# how to fix error in getGEO function?

Tags: r

When I want to use the getGEO function to download GSE dataset with this code:

```
series <- "GSE85358"
gset <- getGEO(series , GSEMatrix =TRUE, AnnotGPL=TRUE, destdir = "....." )
```

I encounter this error:

> https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE2nnn/GSE2553/matrix/ Error
>   in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please include the package where `getGEO` comes from. In addition, [Bioconductor support](https://support.bioconductor.org/) seems to be a better place to ask such such question.